# What is the point of an Expr in vanilla F#? How can it be applied?

Tags: f#

Without using the power pack to convert Expr to C# expressions, it seems like once I create an Expr, the only thing I can do with it is either print out a string representation of it, or...create another Expr.

If I print out a code quotation of an expression, I see that it prints out calls to static Expr methods. How can I use these for something useful?

Comment: Presumably by walking the expression tree and doing stuff with it, but I don't know enough F# specifically to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the ability to be able to [parse an expression using pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx). For example:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

let x = <@@ fun y -> y + 100 @@>

let extractConstantValue = function 
    | Lambda(_, SpecificCall <@@ (+) @@> (_, _, _ :: Value(:? int as constant, _) :: _)) -> constant 
    | _ -> 0

printfn "Value of constant is %O" (extractConstantValue x)
// prints "Value of constant is 100"
```

This gives you all the power to interpret and process expressions, including those generated via the `query` computation expression (clauses in `query` blocks are auto-quoted, i.e. turned into expressions by the compiler). So bearing that in mind, most type providers, such as `OdataService` and `SqlEntityConnection`, are parsers and consumers of query expressions.

Also, providers like [Websharper](http://websharper.com/) translate expressions into Javascript.

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849416/evaluate-quoted-expression-in-f), as you alluded to, compile or evaluate expressions without the Powerpack. Other than that, the possible uses for F# expressions are the same as for .NET expressions. In simple cases, you could use them to describe operations, or to parse a mathematical expression, or to translate simple F# code into some other syntax.

Comment: Thanks! This answer helps fill in a lot of gaps. I thought it was also worth mentioning that a lot of canonical F# resources like to use reflection to get a `MethodInfo` object they can call `Invoke()` on too.